# Find a web address in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a pre-built way to find a url-like string within a string in `ruby`? I have heard of `URI::Extract` but playing around with it, it only seems to find urls prefixed with `http://`

I need to able to find any url-like string in a string, for example:

```
http://test.com
http://www.test.com
www.test.com
test.com
```

Should all be found and returned to me.

I know I could tackle this in regex but I would much rather use anything prebuilt if there it exists. Especially as it should find `.net`, `.org`, `.edu` etc.

Comment: `uri=URI('http://test.com')` `uri.host` ...try this

Comment: What is your definition of a url?  I know one when I see one?

Comment: @7stud did you ask me?

Comment: @7stud Now that I think about it maybe i just need to find any case where the string contains characters a period and then more characters. `something.something`

Comment: `uri=URI('http://test.com')` `uri.host` `uri.host.split(".").last` look at it....

Comment: @rajarshi he is asking something else , please read the question first correctly before giving your comments.

Comment: This seems a valid question, not sure why it's been downvoted. If you have user input, you would want to find anything that the user intended to be 'hyperlinkable' and mark it as such. It's a computing problem and rails is the platform - granted it's a hard problem to solve! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything pre-built for finding "strings with dots in them".  Here's a start for a regex:

```
str =<<END_OF_STRING
http://test.com
hello.
hello http://www.test.com world
.world
hi www.test.com world
test.com
END_OF_STRING


results = str.scan(/
  \S+
  [.]
  \S+
/xms)

--output:--
["http://test.com", "http://www.test.com", "www.test.com", "test.com"]
```

Comment: There is no `s` option for a regex. And since you do not have `.` as a wild character, your `m` option is redundant. Also, I do not see any point in writing such a short regex in three (or five) lines using the `x` option.

Comment: @sawa, In order to normalize regexes, some people write xms for every regex.  The 's' doesn't seem to do any harm in ruby--but point noted.

Comment: Heh, that regex looks like ASCII art.  I'm not sure what of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ruby's builtin URI regex, althout `test.com` won't be a valid URI, so it won't be returned.

```
require 'uri'

string =<<END
http://test.com
http://www.test.com
www.test.com
test.com
END

string.scan(URI.regexp) do |*matches|
    p $&
end
```

If you want you can add another expression to match only hostnames like `test.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to pick up pretty much everything for me:

```
\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|\w+\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))\b/ig
```

It *will* however also pick up things that are not actually valid URL's, like abc.88.

It's derived from the Daring Fireball regex (which doesn't work, at least when copied and pasted, and doesn't detect any domains without either a protocol or the explicit 'www' subdomain).

Answer (score -2):

You could you use a regex to extract URLs. Here's a good regex to start off with:

`` (?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])) ``

Source: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: @pguardiario, Yes it is.  Try: `p "ABC".match /(?i)abc/`. That syntax allows you to do things like this: `p "ABc".match /(?i)ab(?-i)C/`, which allows you to turn flags on and off in the middle of a regex.

Comment: Huh, I never knew that. It's still not a valid regex though.

Comment: The unbroken version (though it still misses on example.com (no protocol or www) and random.example.com (any subdomain other than www): (?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))